# Programing Gateway in C with Sockets

Tags: c, sockets, cygwin, gateway

i am using Cygwin to compile my program and Modbus Poll to send data. My problem is that when i run the file nothing appears. The commented lines give me error when compiling. What i want to do first is receiving data from the Modbus Poll and print it in hexaformat. Then i woul like to separate the information from the header of the sent data. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

typedef struct tcp_pack {
char trans_id[2];
char prot_id[2];
char leng[2];
char unit_id[1];
char apdu[256];
} tcp_pack;


typedef struct ascii_pack {
char start_char;
char addr[2];
char apdu[256];
char lrc[1];
char end_chars[2];
} ascii_pack;


void main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
struct sockaddr_in gw_addr , serv_addr , cli_addr;
int i , j , z , sockfd , newsockfd , portTCP , portserie , modo , n , res;
socklen_t cli_addr_len;
char buffer[256];
tcp_pack tcp1;
ascii_pack ascii1;


for (i=0 ; i<argc ; i++)
{
    if (argv[i][0] == '-')
    {
        switch (argv[i][1])
        {
        case 'p':
            portTCP = atoi(argv[i+1]);
            break;
        case 'c':
            portserie = atoi(argv[i+1]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sockfd < 0)
{
    printf("Erro ao criar Socket");
}

bzero((char *) &gw_addr, sizeof(gw_addr));

gw_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
gw_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;   
gw_addr.sin_port = htons(portTCP);

res = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &gw_addr, sizeof(gw_addr));
if (res < 0)
{
    printf("Erro binding");
}
while(1)
{
    listen(sockfd,5);

    cli_addr_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &cli_addr_len);

    bzero(buffer, 256);


    while ((n = read(newsockfd , buffer , 255) ) >0)
    {
        printf("Mensagem: ");
        for( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
        {
            printf("%X ", buffer[j]);

        }

        /*
        strcpy(tcp1.trans_id , buffer[0] );
        strcpy(tcp1.prot_id , buffer[1] );
        strcpy(tcp1.leng , buffer[2] );
        strcpy(tcp1.unit_id , buffer[3] );
        for( z=0 ; z< buffer[2] ; z++)
        {
            strcpy(tcp1.apdu , buffer[4+z] );
        }

        printf("TI: %X \n",tcp1.trans_id);
        printf("PI: %X \n",tcp1.prot_id);
        printf("L: %X \n",tcp1.leng);
        printf("UID: %X \n",tcp1.unit_id);
        */
        bzero(buffer , 256);
    }
    //close(newsockfd);
    //close(sockfd);
}
```

}

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong? Thanks

EDIT: How i am running my program:

```
$ gcc gateway.c -o gateway
$ ./gateway -p 502 -c 1
```

Comment: Regarding the errors, `strcmp` copies *strings* (pointers to `char`, and zero terminated), `buffer[0]` is a single *character*. `const char *` and `char` is not the same thing.

Comment: Regarding the socket code, call `listen` only once. And *check for errors*! And when you check for errors, do print the actual errors (using e.g. `perror`).